# M_PI not available with gcc --std=c11 but with --std=gnu11?

Tags: c, gcc, c11

I noticed `M_PI` is unavailable on `c11`. By looking at `/usr/include/math.h` I can see `M_PI` is defined if:

```
#if !defined(__STRICT_ANSI__) || ((_XOPEN_SOURCE - 0) >= 500)
...
#define M_PI 3.1415...
#endif
```

Moreover in the `math.h` from [glibc](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=math/math.h;h=c7ff16971e98662081e3192a1269038e9419af59;hb=refs/heads/master) `__STRICT_ANSI__` is replaced with `__USE_MISC`. I am completely lost with this.

What is the story in between `--std=c11` and the constants defined in `math.h`?

Which `libc` should I consider on a `debian` distribution ?

By the way, `M_PI` is defined in `c99` and `gnu11`...

Comment: Why do you have the c++11 tag if what you ask is clearly about C11 and not C++11?

Comment: Yes there is, and your post was already edited to have the c11 tag instead of c++11.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's simple: `M_PI` is not defined in standard C. Provide your own definition if you want to be standard-compliant.

C compilers *cannot* introduce such constants without breaking legal C programs (the name is not reserved, and could be used as an identifier), and as such, they are only defined as an extension.

[GCC 4.9 when used with `-std=c99` doesn't define `M_PI`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d972e64a186ea417), but [does when used with `-std=gnu99`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daded4fdfc402be7)

Comment: It was defined in 'c99' though.

Comment: @coin It shouldn't be - C99 also doesn't define `M_PI`.

Comment: damned, I ignored that I always thought C99 was the default standard for gcc. So what is it then?

Comment: The default of GCC is `gnu90`. 5.1.0 (not released yet) will default to `gnu11`.

Comment: Perhaps one more question. Does `--std=c99` use glibc? If yes, what are the mechanism in gcc that undef `__STRICT_ANSI`?

Comment: @coin: It uses the same libc as with different or without `-std` options (which usually is glibc, but doesn't have to be. E.g. on Windows). Also read http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html for more information.

Comment: @coin Why bother? Either you want more stuff, then you use `-std=gnu99` with extensions, or you don't want extensions because you want portability and don't want to accidentally limit yourself to a single compiler, in that case you use `-std=c99`.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want `M_PI` while looking for a more comprehensive answer with POSIX / XOPEN feature tests macros, etc., an interim solution is:

```
#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI (3.14159265358979323846)
#endif
```

That's "1.20" format, which is also sufficient for 'round-trip' representation for an 80 bit extended type. double precision is "1.16". For 128-bit quad precision:

```
#define M_PI (3.14159265358979323846264338327950288)
```

The "1.35" format for round-trip precision. This means if you want to print out a floating point double, and recover the same value when you read it back, you should use "%+1.16" for printf functions, as so on. You might say that a double doesn't have 17 significant digits, but those digits are not 'junk' if you want to recover a value.

Anyway - there are better resources than this [available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Character_representation).

Comment: For correct 1.16 --> +1.  BTW: See any downside to having lots of PI digits  like 80 digits?

Comment: @chux - not that I can think of. gcc at least includes the gmp / mpfr / mpc libraries to take care of all multiple-precision issues, with correct (and selectable) rounding modes, etc. If an 80 digit PI value was assigned to a single precision float, I would expect it to do the right thing. Don't know how up to date [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath) page is. I don't know clang's approach.

Answer (score 3):

The `M_PI` macro isn't defined by the C11 standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf

Therefore, the `#if` guards are protecting you from problems in case you want to define your own `M_PI` macro. gcc is doing exactly the right thing. The standard headers shouldn't arbitrarily define macros that are not in the standard.