# Is this the right code in computing the volume of a sphere in c?

Tags: c

The problem is:
- Draw a flowchart that computes and print the volume of a sphere. 
- Use the formula: V=r^3 * pi * 4/3. (Where pi is approximately equivalent to 3.1416).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()

{

    float radius, volume;


    printf("Enter the volume of sphere: ");
    scanf("%f", &radius);
    volume = (4.0/3) * (3.1416) * radius * radius * radius;
    printf("Volume of a sphere is : %.3f", volume);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe it’s not right?

Comment: This is my assignment in our school i'm asking if this is the right code for the problem.

Comment: That does not look anything like a flowchart.

Comment: @EvilTeach: Maybe some textual representation? I'd like to see the GUI tool which generates the FC from this.

Comment: I'm confident your teach would tell you. We are not a homework verification service.

Comment: Minor: `3.1416` is a fairly coarse approximation of pi.  Could use `acos(-1)` or 3.1415926535897932384626433832795`

Comment: As [requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814602/is-this-the-right-code-in-computing-the-volume-of-a-sphere-in-c#comment76610527_44814602): @Olaf [code2flow.com: GUI tool which generates the FC from this](https://code2flow.com/72gsnw.png)

Comment: There isn't exactly a lot to flowchart in such a simple program.

Comment: Perhaps a flow chart would expose a fault `"Enter the volume of sphere: "` which should be `"Enter the radius of sphere: "`

Comment: @chux   Consider using the pi constant that is in math.h

Comment: @EvilTeach A compliant C implementation must _not_ define a pi constant like `#define M_PI 3.14...`  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29264462/2410359)

Comment: @EvilTeach with MSVC the `math.h` header will only define `M_PI` (and others) if the programmer enables its extensions with `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` before `#include <math.h>`

Answer (score 0):

If you're gonna include math.h, might as well use it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()

{

    float radius, volume;


    printf("Enter the volume of sphere: ");
    scanf("%f", &radius);
    volume = (4.0/3.0) * (M_PI) * pow(radius, 3);
    printf("Volume of a sphere is : %.3f", volume);

    return 0;
}
```