# What GCC parameters do I need in addition to -std and -pedantic-errors for portability?

Tags: c, gcc, c11, gcc-pedantic

So I used to think using `-std=c11` and `-pedantic-errors` were enough to force `gcc` to only compile code that would also compile on other standard-compliant compilers (possibly on other platforms, assuming no platform-specific libraries are used), such as other versions of gcc or other compilers entirely.

However apparently compiling under mingw on Windows 7 with both `-pedantic-errors -std=c11` allows code to compile that contains this:

```
struct foo {
    //(some members)
};
struct bar {
    struct foo; //note the lack of a member name
    //(other members)
};
```

Which causes the same code, also using gcc with both `-pedantic-errors -std=c11` to fail under Ubuntu with `error: declaration does not declare anything`

If anonymous members like aren't allowed in ISO-C11, then why did gcc let that code pass in the first place? What am I missing about what `-pedantic-errors -std=c11` actually does? What other parameters (if any) do I need to ensure gcc only compiles code that is standard-compliant enough to work under other versions of gcc, on other platforms, and/or other compilers given those compilers are themselves standard-compliant? I.e. make it consistent across platforms.

I am not asking what the purpose of `-pedantic-errors` is, but what parameter(s) can force gcc to only compile code that will compile everywhere (i.e. no gcc-specific extensions or non-standard stuff that doesn't always work). So `-pedantic-errors` but even more strict, as `-pedantic-errors` still allows extensions, it only forbids ones explicity forbidden in the standard.

Comment: It is good idea to also enable `-Wall` and `-Wextra` and possibly `-Werror`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Will look into those, thanks!

Comment: [`-pedantic` explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46233765/918959); [GCC defaults to *GNU11* now instead of strict C11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737104/what-is-the-default-c-mode-for-the-current-gcc-especially-on-ubuntu); Some things that are not standards-compliant visible in [GNU11 but not C11 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264462/m-pi-not-available-with-gcc-std-c11-but-with-std-gnu11) etc...

Comment: Found a line in GCC's docs [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) that answers my question: "A feature to report any failure to conform to ISO C might be useful in some instances, but would require considerable additional work and would be quite different from -Wpedantic. We don’t have plans to support such a feature in the near future." Looks like there is no 100% ISO C option in gcc. Using `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` alongside the pedantic option might be the next best.