# VSCode is throwing 'identifier "M_PI" is undefined'

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I have the following code:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char r[15];
double radius;

double SphereVolume(double radius){
    double volume;

    volume = (4.0 / 3.0) * (M_PI) * (pow(radius, 3.0)); ///'identifier "M_PI" is undefined' 
    return (volume);
}

int main()
{
    /* gets input from the user */
    printf("What is the radius of the Sphere? ");
    fgets(r, sizeof(r), stdin);
    sscanf(r, "%lf", &radius);

    printf("Volume of the sphere is %f", SphereVolume(radius));
    return (0);
}
```

I can run it well with gcc by doing:

`$> gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -o SphereVolume SphereVolume.c -lm`

But VS Code isn't letting me even debugging the code. What is happening? do I have messed up settings?

Comment: *"isn't letting me even debugging the code"* This is unrelated to the macro-related errors you get, but it's hard to say anything else without knowing the details.

Comment: `M_PI` is not a standard macro.  No surprise it is missing here as code does not define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer:

[M_PI not available with gcc --std=c11 but with --std=gnu11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264462/m-pi-not-available-with-gcc-std-c11-but-with-std-gnu11)

Apparently M_PI is not defined in standard C